# SqlCommand error "Conversion failed," though variable and returned value both string

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm new to `C#`, so forgive me if my lingo is amateur.

I have a method that executes a Stored Procedure in my Service-Based Database. The SP returns a single char(32) value, which I am attempting to assign to a string variable. But I get an error message indicating a conversion failure:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClients.SqlException'
>   occured in System.Data.dll Additional information: Conversion failed
>   when converting the varchar value '...correct alphanumeric char(32)
>   value here...' to datatype int.

I can't figure out why it thinks there's an `INT` conversion going on anywhere. I even add an explicit (string) declaration to the `ExecuteScalar()`, but with no effect.

Here's the method:

```
internal static string getAuthKey(string ClientNo)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Constants.DbConnString); //Define db connection
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetAuthKey", con); //Define db command
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientNo",ClientNo); //Specify parameter value
    con.Open(); //Open connection
    string AuthKey = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //Execute procedure, store result
    /\ ***Error occurs on line above*** /\
    con.Close(); //Close connection
    return AuthKey;
}
```

... and the method call from Main()...

```
string ClientNo = "00500";
string AuthKey = Constants.getAuthKey(ClientNo);
```

Stored Procedure code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAuthKey] @ClientNo char(5) AS
DECLARE @AuthKey CHAR(32);
SET @AuthKey =
(   SELECT TOP 1 AuthKey
    FROM dbo.AuthKey
    WHERE ClientNo = @ClientNo )
RETURN @AuthKey
```

Comment: The error is happening inside your procedure. Can you post that SQL?

Comment: Are you sure `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` does not return null?

Comment: What are the SQL Types of the AuthKey & ClientNo columns in the AuthKey table?

Comment: dbo.AuthKey table is: ClientNo CHAR(5) PK, AuthKey CHAR(32)

Comment: @Matt, My earlier fix or the attempt was wrong, I believe you have to add the parameter like: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientNo", SqlDbType.Char).Value = ClientNo;`

Comment: the error is here : cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientNo",ClientNo);

Comment: @Habib, gave it a try, same error.

Comment: @user3420762, the error message tells me the returned value, which is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `RETURN` statement with your parameter, which is a `char`. RETURN types expect an `int` which is where the error is occurring.

`ExecuteScalar()` returns the first column in the first row, and you are not including a result set.

Change it to

```
 SELECT @AuthKey
```

Comment: We have a winner! I also wrapped my procedure in BEGIN ... END, but that resolved it!